# Skip onboarding screens after appUser has scrolled through all screens?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

How can I ensure that the appUser does not have to slide through all of the onboarding screens each time they open the app? I have 4 onboarding screens leading to a signup/login screen.

Answer (score 3):

When your user has finished viewing the onboarding screens, you can do `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "userDidFinishOnboarding")`, and the next time you launch, you can check if `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("userDidFinishOnboarding")` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

As OP has tagged Swift,

**In Swift3+**

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isOnboardingDone") == true {
     //Skip onboarding
} else {
     //Show onboarding screens
     UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isOnboardingDone")
}
```